# Incorrect vertical spacing inside a mdframed environment

Tags: spacing, mdframed

I have some problems about vertical spacing before and after some environments inside a mdframed environment. It is as if `topsep=0`. The insertion of `\setlengh{\topsep}{8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt}` fixes the problem except for the first list environment inside each mdframed environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}    
\verb?\topsep?=\the\topsep

\begin{mdframed}
\verb?\topsep?=\the\topsep

\lipsum[11]

\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb?\topsep?=\the\topsep
\end{itemize}                      

\lipsum[11]

\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb?\topsep?=\the\topsep
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{verbatim}
  $[G\colon H\cap K] = [G\colon H][H\colon H\cap K]$
\end{verbatim}

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[11]
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[11]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which version do you use? With the current one it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current version of `mdframed` the issue is fixed:

[image]